# c# How to Recursively delete objects and its children

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

This is my function that gives me a list of nodes based on its parentId:

```
public List<RepositoriesListViewModel> GetChildren(string ParentId)
{
    List<RepositoriesListViewModel> data = new List<RepositoriesListViewModel>();
    List<RepositoriesListViewModel> initialData = new List<RepositoriesListViewModel>();
    var List = dbContext.Repositories.ToList();
    foreach (var item in List)
    {
        initialData.Add(new RepositoriesListViewModel
        {
            id = item.Id,
            parent = item.ParentId,
            ApplicationsId = item.ApplicationsId,
            text = item.Name,
            Path = item.Path,
            CreatedOn = item.CreatedOn
        });
    };
    foreach (RepositoriesListViewModel child in initialData.Where(x => x.parent == ParentId))
    {
        child.Children = GetChildren(child.id);
        data.Add(child);
    }
    return data;
}
```

I was wondering if it were possible to delete an item and its children using this function as well? Where would I add my delete call?

This is what my delete call looks like:

```
public void Delete(string Input)
{
    try
    {
        var repo = Get(Input);
        dbContext.Repositories.Remove(repo);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        logger.LogInformation(LoggingGlobals.Delete + " Repository: " + repo.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogError(e, "Failed to delete Repository");
    }
}
```

Comment: In your remove/destroy function inside your object , 1- Detach from parent 2- call remove for all the children 3- remove your self from the repository if you are in its list

Comment: Sorry what do you mean detach from parent?

Comment: i mean when an object's remove/destroy is called, it should first remove itself from any parent it has, obviously if an object has children, it must have a parent as well, so in case an object is destroyed or removed, it must first detach it self from its parent, in another world, `Detach from parent` means, removing yourself from the children list of your parent.

Comment: So what happens in `data` list after deleting item and its child? its also deleted from this list?

Comment: @er-sho the intention is that the parent and all children should be deleted

Comment: @JianYA, Suppose your recursive function delete outer most parent then its all child so for next recursion there is no any child present that supoose retrieve parent from those deleted child. Means if parent deleted then all childs in hierarchy are deleted so no recursion would help in this case

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want something like this:

```
public void Delete(string Input)
{
    try
    {
        var children = GetChildren(Input);

        foreach(var child in children)
        {
            Delete(child.Id);
        }

        var repo = Get(Input);
        dbContext.Repositories.Remove(repo);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
        logger.LogInformation(LoggingGlobals.Delete + " Repository: " + repo.Name);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.LogError(e, "Failed to delete Repository");
    }
}
```

So Before you delete the item itself, you first delete its children and their children.